# Can women lead in other positions

Tags: hadith-interpretation

I know that a woman is not allowed to lead a country or become a judge. But is the narration in Bukhari which says “No people will succeed those who make women rule over them” general? I mean, can’t a woman lead in any position? Let’s suppose that she started a business. Is it haram for her to lead it?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE. I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help] to learn more about our site and what is on- or off-topic here.